# VMWare Player 6 start command line

Tags: linux, command-line, vmware, vmware-player

i learned that vix doesnt support vmware player 6. Does anyone know how to achive the same commands vmrun did offer for the previous verison of the player?

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu

```
sudo vmplayer
```

from terminal.

Moore info: https://www.vmware.com/pdf/desktop/vmware_player60.pdf

Comment: iv already checked. thats not possible. it would just open you a new windows.

Comment: You need to run it *without* sudo   otherwise you are running as root and will see a bunch of other (or no) vms.